# CSS Selectors Confusion

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand selectors if I had something like

```
#topbar .ink-navigation ul.black li a.logoPlaceholder
```

does it mean I can issue a

```
<li class="logoPlaceholder">
```

or

```
<a href="" class="logoPlaceholder">Test</a></li>
```

Comment: this might help you... https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of css selector tricks you can do, I started studying css selector in this [CSS game](http://flukeout.github.io/)

But let me answer what's that selector is calling ..

**#topbar .ink-navigation ul.black li a.logoPlaceholder**

so basically this select an **a tag** element that has a class of logoPlaceholder inside an **li** that is also inside in a **ul tag** with a class **.black** which is also inside in a element with a class **.ink-navigation** with a parent element that has an id **topbar**

**Edit: Added a code to demonstrate what I mean:**

```
<nav id="topbar">
    <div class="ink-navigation">
        <ul class="black">
            <li>
                //Selectors call this element.
                <a class="logoPlaceholder"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="white">
            <li>
                //Selectors won't call this because li tag was not inside a ul with a class of black.
                <a class="logoPlaceholder"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one is correct.

```
a.logoPlaceholder
```

Means that the `<a>` tag has the class `logoPlaceholder`, like this:

```
`<a class="logoPlaceholder" href="#">Link text</a>`
```

In fact, it is also telling you that the basic HTML scaffolding looks something like this:

```
<tag id="topbar">
    <tag class="ink-navigation">
        <ul class="black">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="logoPlaceholder">
```

The elements that are labelled `tag` are not specified, so impossible if they are DIVs or NAV or ASIDE or SECTION or ? *(But, I would guess the first one is a NAV and the second is a DIV)*